# applescript: get answer and buttons of display dialog

Tags: display, applescript, dialog

How do I get both the answer and the button pressed of a display dialog on applescript?

The following code will get me the text, but not the button:

```
set myquestion to the text returned of (display dialog "hallo" ¬
          buttons {"h", "a"} default button "a" default answer "")
```

But how do I get the button which was pressed? I know I can use the following:

```
set mybutton to button returned of (display dialog "hallo" ¬
          buttons {"h", "a"} default button "a" default answer "")
```

But how to I get both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *result* returned of a `display dialog` *command* is a `record`, which is a collection of *labeled properties*, and as such you can code it so the *variable* contains the whole `record` and thus afterwards assign a *variable* for each *labeled property* within the *record* as in the following example:

```
set theResultReturned to (display dialog "hallo" buttons {"h", "a"} default button "a" default answer "")
set theTextReturned to the text returned of theResultReturned
set theButtonReturned to the button returned of theResultReturned
```

- Note the use of `the` in `to the ...` can be omitted if you want to be less verbose. Also the *variable* names can be less verbose as well and were written in this manner for clarity.

You can then act upon the assigned *variables* as needed/wanted.

Unless for reasons of how/why you're coding it necessitates it, you also can code it in a manner in which separate *variables* for each *labeled property* do not have to be explicitly set. For an example *logic flow* without explicit setting of *labeled properties*, have a look at the Examples section of the [`display dialog`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW12) *command* in the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).