# How to include variables in the text shown in a osascript display dialog

Tags: terminal, display, applescript, dialog

[image: screenshot of the display dialog]

I'm creating a cool script to bother me by asking to close the app with the name of the variable after the specified minutes. The `osascript` `display dialog` is become more complex. Now [it's working thanks to the help got here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458153/177042).

But I'm not being able to get the variable `PROCESS_NAME` properly:

```
PROCESS_NAME="Telegram" 
DIALOG_RESULTS="$(osascript -e 'set {T,B} to {text returned, button returned} of (display dialog "Minutes to remember to close $((PROCESS_NAME))" default answer "1" with icon caution buttons {"Keep Open", "CLOSE APP & take a break"} default button 1)' -e 'return T & "\t" & B')" &&MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE="$(echo "$DIALOG_RESULTS" |cut -f 1)" &&BUTTON_RETURNED="$(echo "$DIALOG_RESULTS" |cut -f 2)"
```

The current (wrong) output is this:

> Minutes to remember to close **$((PROCESS_NAME))**

The desired (correct) output should be:

> Minutes to remember to close **Telegram**

Comment: Replace `$((PROCESS_NAME))` with `'"$PROCESS_NAME"'`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson working! If you with to create an answer to mark it as the solution... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$((PROCESS_NAME))` with `'"$PROCESS_NAME"'`.

Explanation:

This change results in the following three strings, which are adjacent to each other:

```
'set {T,B} to {text returned, button returned} of (display dialog "Minutes to remember to close '
"$PROCESS_NAME"
'" default answer "1" with icon caution buttons {"Keep Open", "CLOSE APP & take a break"} default button 1)'
```

The second string `"$PROCESS_NAME"` contains a variable which, when replaced by the variable's contents, becomes `"Telegram"`. Since the three strings are adjacent (there are no other characters between them), the strings can be concentrated to form the single string given below.

```
'set {T,B} to {text returned, button returned} of (display dialog "Minutes to remember to close Telegram" default answer "1" with icon caution buttons {"Keep Open", "CLOSE APP & take a break"} default button 1)'
```