# convert or parse float to int in bash script fails in several ways

Tags: command-line, bash

We have:

```
MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE="0,2"
number_of_iterations=$((MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE * 60 / 5))
```

There are a couple of weird behaviors when doing that.

Firstly, the result should be:

> number_of_iterations = 0,2 * 60 / 5 = 2,4

However, the output of: `echo "number_of_iterations" $((MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE * 60 / 5))` is:

> 24

Secondly, I want to use it in the loop `for ((a=1; a<=$number_of_iterations; a++)); do`, it should be an integer. So actually the final desired output is:

> 2

How to do this this rounding of variables of float to int in applescript correctly?

I've tried the following, but it crashes the script:

```
echo "number_of_iterations" $((round(MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE * 60 / 5))
```

---

After the comments asking to clarify and show the whole, I'm happy to share the whole script. It works (feel free to use it for yourself) if you set `DEFAULT_MINUTES_1` with an int like `DEFAULT_MINUTES_1="1"`. It fails if I set a float like: `DEFAULT_MINUTES_1="0,2"`. It doesn't work either if I do: `DEFAULT_MINUTES_1="0.2"`

```
#!/bin/bash
    
PROCESS_NAME="Telegram" 
    
DIALOG_TEXT_1="Minutes to remember to close $PROCESS_NAME:"
BUTTON_TEXT_OPEN_1="Open $PROCESS_NAME"
BUTTON_TEXT_CLOSE_1="Close $PROCESS_NAME & take a break"
DEFAULT_MINUTES_1="0,2"
    
DIALOG_TEXT_2="Minutes to remember to close $PROCESS_NAME:"
BUTTON_TEXT_OPEN_2="Keep Open $PROCESS_NAME"
BUTTON_TEXT_CLOSE_2="Close $PROCESS_NAME & take a break"
DEFAULT_MINUTES_2="0,2"

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set visible of front window to true'
    
# Got help from here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/458152/177042 and here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/460004/177042
DIALOG_RESULTS="$(osascript -e 'set {T,B} to {text returned, button returned} of (display dialog "'"$DIALOG_TEXT_1"'" default answer "'"$DEFAULT_MINUTES_1"'" with icon caution buttons {"'"$BUTTON_TEXT_OPEN_1"'", "'"$BUTTON_TEXT_CLOSE_1"'"} default button 2)' -e 'return T & "\t" & B')" &&MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE="$(echo "$DIALOG_RESULTS" |cut -f 1)" &&BUTTON_RETURNED="$(echo "$DIALOG_RESULTS" |cut -f 2)"
    
echo "DIALOG_RESULTS" $DIALOG_RESULTS
echo "MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE" $MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE
echo "BUTTON_RETURNED" $BUTTON_RETURNED
    
MINUTES_APP_OPENED=$(($MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE))
    
if [ "$BUTTON_RETURNED" = "$BUTTON_TEXT_OPEN_1" ] ; then
    open -a "$PROCESS_NAME"
else 
    exit
fi

echo "number_of_iterations" $((MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE * 60 / 5))

for ((i=0; i<=1000; i++)); do

    # Sleep during the time indicated on the variable: MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE
    # But each 5 seconds, checks if the app has been closed or not to close this terminal if so     
    number_of_iterations=$((MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE * 60 / 5))
    for ((a=1; a<=$number_of_iterations; a++)); do
        if pgrep "$PROCESS_NAME"; then
            sleep 5
        else
            exit
        fi
    done

    MINUTES_APP_OPENED=$((MINUTES_APP_OPENED+$MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE*$i))
    echo "----"
    echo
    echo "$PROCESS_NAME has been openened during $MINUTES_APP_OPENED minutes"
    DIALOG_RESULTS="$(osascript -e 'set {T,B} to {text returned, button returned} of (display dialog "'"$DIALOG_TEXT_2"'" default answer "'"$DEFAULT_MINUTES_2"'" with icon caution buttons {"'"$BUTTON_TEXT_OPEN_2"'", "'"$BUTTON_TEXT_CLOSE_2"'"} default button 1)' -e 'return T & "\t" & B')" &&MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE="$(echo "$DIALOG_RESULTS" |cut -f 1)" &&BUTTON_RETURNED="$(echo "$DIALOG_RESULTS" |cut -f 2)"

    echo "In $MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE minutes, you will be asked again if you want close $PROCESS_NAME "

    if [ "$BUTTON_RETURNED" = "$BUTTON_TEXT_CLOSE_2" ] ; then
        pkill -x "$PROCESS_NAME"
        echo "OK pressed. $PROCESS_NAME should be closed now"
        exit
    else
        echo "Cancel pressed. $PROCESS_NAME won't be killed... Yet :D"
        echo
        echo "----"
    fi
done

exit
```

Comment: First guess is it isn't parsing a comma as a decimal, try 0.2 Second is, though I'm far, *far* from an Applescript expert, I don't think I've ever seen a $ sign in one.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't look anything like Applescript at all, using answer space for format. **Please clarify.**

Comment: Looking at your recent question history, I see this probably is part of a larger issue & your question snippet gives no hint as to what the overall problem actually is. You need to give *minimum reproducible examples* because we are not mind readers.

Comment: Is this a shell's scripting language instead, e.g. zsh or bash? It's definitely not AppleScript.

Comment: This is shell script code, but shell scripts only work with integers. Also, I wonder what you are going to do within the `for` loop, so maybe you can focus the question on what you actually want to accomplish at the end.

Comment: The above syntax is not AppleScript. Under Bash or Zsh, `$((MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE * 60 / 5))` would be the same as `$(((0,2) * 60 / 5))` which is executed using the C language rules. First, the `0,2` is executed left to right with the right most value being the result. So the `0` is not used and the result is `2`. The expression reduces down to `2 * 60 / 5`, which results in `24`.

Comment: I can offer an example showing that I am correct about the use of the comma (`,`). Enter `j=$((i=5,i+2))` in Bash or Zsh. The variable `i` will be set to `5` and the variable `j` will be set to `7`.

Comment: I never knew until now the variable could contain an expression. I am amused at the order of evaluation. For example, `unset i;i="5+4";echo $(($i*2))` results is `13` and `unset i;i="5+4";echo $((i*2))` results in `18`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Shell expansion rules sometimes are magic, but the main point here is that variables aren‘t typed by default.

Comment: Anyway, I don‘t think that the OP was looking at `,` as an operator, pretty sure they meant `0.2`.

Comment: @Tetsujin with `0.2`, it seems to crash. That's why I thought the correct way was `0,2`. The reason I shared just a part of the code is to try to make it easier and quick to understand and reply. I've updated it with the whole code now after your comment. Also: feel free to change applescript by the correct language. I thought it was applescript cause it's a script for apple and display dialog I believe is applescript!

Comment: @nohillside if it's not possible to work with decimals with this kind of scripts (which would be really weird to me), that would explain everything. Then I guess I could think some creative solution like a big `if clause` if a comma or point is found to contemplate all possibilities

Comment: Regarding Applescript vs shell script: It helps to know which scripting language to use, as it makes looking up things in manuals or Google a lot simpler.

Comment: @nohillside it has been really hard to find good information actually... I guess because I was performing google searches like `applescript round float it` xD

Comment: ["bash float"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+float&ia=web) would have given you the answer right away :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can‘t do floating point math directly in shell scripts, see the "arithmetic evaluation" section in `man bash` for details.

You can use `bc` instead (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222250/floating-point-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-script), but for your script that's way too complicated. You are better off by using seconds instead of minutes for all the numbers and adjust the calculations accordingly. If you want to give users the opportunity to still enter minutes, just multiply with 60 afterwards.

PS: Some more feedback on your code:

- You don't seem to use the `i` variable of the outer loop, so you could replace `for ((i=0; i<=1000; i++)); do` with `while true; do` to get an endless loop.
- `MINUTES_APP_OPENED=$(($MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE))` would only be required if `MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE` is an arithmetic expression like `5*12`. Not sure what you expect users to enter in the dialog, but if the input is just a number, `MINUTES_APP_OPENED=MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE` will do.

Comment: From the **coding perspective**, agree to type seconds. But from the **user perspective**, I don't have it so clear: if it's 20 seconds yes, but if the person wants to set 25 minutes, then it's not so instant to calculate how many seconds and to type them down (probably multiple times per day). And yes: I didn't even understand [the solution of that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222250/floating-point-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-script). Maybe if I take some more time, I will end up understanding it though. Thank you!!

Comment: @chelder You can easily ask the user for minutes and then use `((60 * user_input))` within the script.

Comment: Thanks for the extra feedback! :) I understand that because can‘t do floating point math directly in bash scripts (is it the same than shell scripts?), I have to execute another language (which one is the name? Is that applescript) within the bash script

Comment: I'm not being able to make it work. I tried below the `DIALOG_RESULTS=(...)` the following: `MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE=$(($MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE * 60))`
Unfortunately, with `0,2` the result is still **120 instead 12** and with `0.2` it **crashes**. The script is closed (I even put a pause right after it), so I can't see any error message.

Comment: @chelder Bash is one of the shells used for shell scripting (and for interactive use, of course). `bc` is a Unix utility which does floating point math (see `man bc` for details). But as mentioned already: You **don't** need floating point for your script, it just makes it more complicated.

Comment: @chelder If you expect people to enter `0,2` for 12 seconds, then you need to untangle the part before and after the `,`. There are ways to do this in Bash, but please read up on the topic first.

Comment: @chelder and of course it crashes, it can't handle floating points like `0.2`. `0,2` does something completely different, see comments below the question for details.

Comment: Finally it's working with this: `MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE=$( echo "scale=0;($MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE*60+0.5)/1" | bc )` Next I'll rename `MINUTES_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE` by `SECONDS_UNTIL_ASK_TO_CLOSE` just for the beauty. Sometimes because the locale it's `0.2` or `0,2`. In this case it's `0.2` the way to go. Thanks so much for all the help and lessons learnt today about this!!! :)